# Magento2 - Integrity constraint violation 1062 ALTER TABLE on setup:upgrade

Tags: database, magento2.3.5

`Magento 2.3.5` `Mariadb 10.2` `PHP 7.2`

We are hitting the **constraint violation** error below when running: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
`catalog_product_entity_varchar` ran out of space at 2147483647 so we increased the `value_id` **int** to **Bigint**.

We are able to edit and add products again. But now have the constraint error coming up when it reaches schema / update.
What is the best way to correct this, can we change the constraint rule?

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
1062 ALTER TABLE causes auto_increment resequencing,
resulting in duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY',
query was: ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar` MODIFY COLUMN
`value_id` int(11)  NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT "Value ID"

Thanks so much.

Comment: I think the path to change the Rule is here: /public_html/magento/module-rule/Model/Resource/Model/Rule/Collection/AbstractCollection.php? But out of my depth. Basically we now have a site that cannot be upgraded. If anyone can point me in the right direction. Not having changed Integer would have meant the site was not longer usable. We are willing to pay to have this resolved.

Comment: Ok, think I have found the answer, will try this shortly and update here:
grep -r -l "catalog_product_entity_varchar"
Found:
vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/db_schema.xml
Located the table causing the issue:
<table name="catalog_product_entity_varchar" resource="default" engine="innodb"
comment="Catalog Product Varchar Attribute Backend Table">
<column xsi:type="int" name="value_id" padding="11" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true"
comment="Value ID"/>
So changing int to bigint should fix the problem.
Just one question, what could be the consequences?

Comment: Problem fixed, hope this helps someone. We have 187885 products and 408 attributes. We certainly didn't expect the catalog_product_entity_varchar table to max out.

Comment: Same issue, any solution?

Answer (score 2):

@MHK Developer is correct by increasing the type to `bigint` however I would suggest additionally changing to `unsigned` instead of `signed` doubling the amount of records in the table can hold.

`value_id` is an MySQL auto increment, and therefore will the entire space below 0 is wasted.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="catalog_product_entity_varchar" resource="default">
        <column xsi:type="bigint" name="value_id" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Value ID"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Tonygo Thanks

Found: vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/db_schema.xml Located the table causing the issue:

```
<table name="catalog_product_entity_varchar" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Catalog Product Varchar Attribute Backend Table"> 
<column xsi:type="int" name="value_id" padding="11" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Value ID"/>
```

So changing int to bigint should fix the problem.

Its look like

```
 <column xsi:type="bigint " name="value_id" padding="11" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Value ID"/>
```

Comment: To do this in a custom extension, simply create a *db_schema.xml* for that extension and make sure the extension depends on *Magento_Catalog*, to overwrite the field definition.